# Moving computer, how to move Microsoft Office and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office

I'm changing my computer.

I currently have Microsoft Office 2010 Professional (which I got from the academic promotion 'Ultimate Steal') and Windows 7 64-bit (which I got from MSDNAA) installed.

I have the serial codes for each, and can probably obtain an ISO file for Windows.

However, how do you actually de-register Office and Windows so you can re-enter the serial number on a new machine?

Also I don't have a CD or .exe file for Office 2010, where can I download it? (I can no longer download the file from where I bought it because it is too long after I purchased it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to deactivate them, Just re-enter the product keys. Typically there is a set number of times you can enter the product key before you will have to call Microsoft, I know with Office it is three times. Just enter them again when reinstalling and you should be able to reactivate them. If there is an issue you can always call Microsoft they offer free assistance with activation and have a fairly easy to use automated system for getting your product activated.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much, that is exactly what I was hoping to hear :D